# Filter specific lines from directory tree listing

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

I have the following directory listing:

```
    /home/a/b/c/d/5089/294265
    /home/a/b/c/d/5089/79783
    /home/a/b/c/d/41630
    /home/a/b/c/d/41630/293520
    /home/a/b/c/d/41630/293520/293520
...
```

I want to filter only the lines that go 7 directories deep. In this example I would need only the line: /home/a/b/c/d/41630/293520/293520

Please suggest.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use `grep`.  Saying:

```
grep -P '(/[^/]*){8}' inputfile
```

would return

```
/home/a/b/c/d/41630/293520/293520
```

---

Not sure how you are generating this listing, but if you were using `find` you could control the depth by specifying `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` options.

Comment: I generated the list using: find /home/x/y/z/ -print > out.txt

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
find /home/x/y/z/ -print | awk -F/ 'NF>8'
```

or you could try

```
find /home/x/y/z/ -mindepth 7 -print
```

Answer (score 1):

```
YourInput | sed 's|/.|&|7;t
d'
```

remove line with less than 7 "/" followed by something

Answer (score 0):

```
echo /home/a/b/c/d/*/*/*
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
find /home| awk -F \/ 'NF==9' file
```